# How to stop nodeos from generating a message every block

Tags: nodeos

[image]

How to stop nodeos from generating a message every block? I was trying to do the tutorial and have to have nodeos running in the background but how do I do the tutorial without nodeos showing a message every half second?

Comment: Command + T will create a new window in terminal, I use that.

Comment: I used nodeos & and it is still showing me messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run nodeos in the background. (add '&' at the end of command line)

$ nodeos &

And if you don't want to see messages from nodeos, then use following command.

$ nohup nodeos > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Answer (score 0):

Here's the line in producer_plugin.cpp:

```
   ilog("Produced block ${id}... #${n} @ ${t} signed by ${p} [trxs: ${count}, lib: ${lib}, confirmed: ${confs}]",
        ("p",new_bs->header.producer)("id",fc::variant(new_bs->id).as_string().substr(0,16))
        ("n",new_bs->block_num)("t",new_bs->header.timestamp)
        ("count",new_bs->block->transactions.size())("lib",chain.last_irreversible_block_num())("confs", new_bs->header.confirmed));
```

If you look at the definition of `ilog` you'll see that it logs if the logging level is info:

```
#define ilog( FORMAT, ... ) \
  FC_MULTILINE_MACRO_BEGIN \
   if( (fc::logger::get(DEFAULT_LOGGER)).is_enabled( fc::log_level::info ) ) \
      (fc::logger::get(DEFAULT_LOGGER)).log( FC_LOG_MESSAGE( info, FORMAT, __VA_ARGS__ ) ); \
  FC_MULTILINE_MACRO_END
```

And so there's probably a way to set the log level to something lower than info.  Or, if you're like me, just delete that line and recompile.  That's not something I'd do for production, but it's fine if you're running a development node.